# How to enable CreateQuerylog in Azure Analysis Service?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-analysis-services

[image]

How to change CreateQueryLog value and QueryConnectionString in azure analysis services?

Comment: What are you referring to by "CreateQueryLog"?

Comment: I wanted to log different activities occurring on azure analysis Server. Thus, to Configure  Log\QueryLog\ CreateQueryLogTable and Log\QueryLog\ QueryLogConnectionString from azure analysis properties.